# Continuously updating Pose of a link in a plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I need to continuously update the pose of a link, in the OnUpdate function.

What function from the API can I use for it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12756/continuously-updating-pose-of-a-link-in-a-plugin/) by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could use [Link::SetWorldPose](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Entity.html#ab4245b6d8170fae923a25a4f00e52708) for example, but note that this will override the physics engine, so things like gravity will be neglected.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on 2016-03-01**:
Is there any way, by which gravity cannot be neglected?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-03-01**:
If you set the pose to be 10m above ground for example, that will move the object regardless of other forces in the world. If you apply force instead, the resulting position will be a combination of all the forces applied. To reach a specific position by applying force, you'll probably need something like a PID controller.